# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. only when published

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate

I have a weird problem.

While I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to run my website (IIS Express) I have no issue contacting https://sysorgoauth2.[HIDDEN].se/oauth2/v1/sysorg/token to retrive a token.

However as soon as I publish my site on my local IIS, I get error message "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.".

I'm using our companies certificate "server identification/organizational" .p12 certificate to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I changed the ApplicationPool Identity to "LocalSystem" instead of the default "ApplicationIdentity" in IIS.